# Java Streams Api как отфильтровать список используя список условий произвольной длины?

Tags: java, android, java-stream

Можно ли с помощью StreamAPi (пользуюсь StreamSupport), реализовать фильтрацию списка по переменному количеству условий? Например у сущности есть поле, которое содержит набор каких то битовых флагов. Соответственно из списка сущностей надо вытащить те, которые по флагам проходят

```
public static List<Entity> filter(List<Entity> data, int... flags){}
```

На данный момент я это делаю так

```
public static List<Entity> filter(List<Entity> data, int... flags) {
    return StreamSupport.stream(data)
            .filter(entity-> {
                for (int flag : flags) {
                    if ((flag & entity.getFlags()) > 0) {
                        return true;
                    }
                }

                return false;
            }).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Можно ли реализовать это более кратко и изящно? На данный момент всё, что пришло на ум это

```
public static List<Entity> filter(List<Entity> data, int... flags) {
    return StreamSupport.stream(data)
            .filter(entity ->
                    StreamSupport.stream(Arrays.asList(flags)).anyMatch(flag -> (entity.getFlafs() & flag) > 0))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Хотелось бы сократить это еще больше

Comment: Зачем использовать `StreamSupport`, если у списков уже есть метод `stream()`?

Comment: @AlexChermenin В андроиде стримы только с семерки работают гарантированно. Даже с 7.1.1 вроде

Comment: если флаги - степени двойки, то можно их сложить в один `int` и написать `entity -> entity.getFlags() & flags != 0`

Answer (score 0):

Рефакторинг стоит начать не здесь, так как при уходе от императивного стиля, само назначение метода, принимающего список с переменным набором флагов и и возвращающий другой список, становится сомнительным. Но если оставаться в пределах установленных вопросом рамок, то свёртка набора предикатов будет более идиоматичной, чем цикл в одном предикате.

```
public static List<Entity> filter(List<Entity> data, int... flags) {
    Predicate<Entity> p = Arrays.stream(flags)
                                .map(f -> e -> (f & e.getFlags()) > 0)
                                .reduce(Predicate::or)
                                .orElse(t -> false);

    return data.stream()
               .filter(p)
               .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Естественно, можно обойтись без переменной `p`, засунув свёртку предикатов внутрь `filter`. Разделил их для наглядности.