# Где можно использовать методы Predicate?

Tags: java, java-8

Интересуют случаи где можно применить `negate`, `and` и `or`. Ну и к тому же не пойму в общем как они работают. Объясните пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1):

Предположим у вас есть предикат, который единожды сохранён в переменную и используется во многих участках кода. Для простоты возьмём ссылку на метод `isEmpty` класса `String`, проверяющий строку на пустоту:

```
Predicate<String> isEmpty = String::isEmpty;
```

Но в одних участках кода надо использовать его для нахождения пустых строк, а в других наоборот непустых. Например, вы считали из файла строки и хотите отбросить пустые:

```
Files.lines(Paths.get(fileName))
     .filter(isEmpty.negate())
     ...
```

Без метода `negate` вам пришлось бы использовать более многословную и менее идиоматичную конструкцию с дополнительной лямбдой:

```
Files.lines(Paths.get(fileName))
     .filter(s -> !isEmpty.test(s))
     ...
```

*Повторюсь, `isEmpty` используется только для примера. Тут мог бы быть какой-нибудь нестандартный и более сложный предикат.*

Методы `or` и `and` позволяют объединять предикаты, благодаря чему можно, например, в одной операции `filter` выполнить цепочку проверок. Вот пример из моего другого [ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/809621/204271), динамический конструирующий предикат из набора заранее неизвестных условий:

```
Predicate<Entity> p = Arrays.stream(flags)
                            .map(f -> e -> (f & e.getFlags()) > 0)
                            .reduce(Predicate::or)
                            .orElse(t -> false);

data.stream()
    .filter(p)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```